# slds styles apply on <button> but don't apply on <apex:commandButton>

Tags: visualforce, lightning

I apply slds styles on apex:commandButton, but it does it not as in [docs](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/buttons/) but in a strange way:

1. Standard apex:commandbutton without styles
2. apex:commandbutton with styleClass="slds-button"
3. Button without style.
4. Button with clas="slds-button"

[image: 4 buttons only last with the needed style]

Code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountExtension"  sideBar="false">

        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.sfdc_lightning, 'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css')}" />


    <apex:outputPanel id="test">
        <apex:form >
            <div class="slds">
                <div id="startButtonDiv" class="slds-button">
                    <apex:commandButton value="Start" action="{!redirectToProcessing}" id="standardApexButton" rendered="{!showStartButton}" rerender="none"/>
                    <apex:commandButton value="Start" action="{!redirectToProcessing}" id="StyledApexButton" rendered="{!showStartButton}" rerender="none" styleClass="slds-button"/>
                    <button id="NormalButton">Start</button>
                    <button id="styledNormalButton" class="slds-button">Start</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

Is there a way to apply styles to apex:commandButton so it will look like a last styled button?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: try standardstylesheet=false

Comment: Tried, nothing's changed :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong stylesheet. If you want your Visualforce to look more like Lightning, use "salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css" instead. Also, see the SLDS topic on [Visualforce](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/visualforce/) for some gotchas you'll want to know about while using SLDS in Visualforce.

Comment: @EvAzi You're welcome! I'm still learning SLDS myself, but this was literally the first problem I ran into on my new pages. You should use the VF version for any component that will eventually end up on a VF page, as noted in the documentation.

Comment: How can I get this CSS? Is it already in SF?

Comment: @patriciajlim Yes, use [`apex:slds`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_slds.htm) to use the CSS in Visualforce.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use:

```
<apex:page lightningStylesheets="true">
```

see: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.210.0.pages.meta/pages/vf_dev_best_practices_slds_lightningstylesheets.htm